# on Magento2.1 how to import product with multiple category

Tags: magento-2.1, product, import, category-products, import-products

Now i try

Default `Category/Main/sub` ,
Default `Category/Main2/sub2`

Default `Category/Main/sub` is working fine 
but in Default `Category/Main2/sub2` can't import product

> **Error** Category Default `Category/Main2/sub2` has not been created. URL
>   key for specified store already exists.

Comment: Is there any category named **sub2** in your admin? If so, have you created this category from admin or it's been created at the time of csv import?

Comment: Go to admin > catalog > category > sub2 and try to save this category and check if it is saved or throwing any error.

Comment: i created category named sub2 from admin. i will import product to sub2

Comment: " , " for separator category. it right ?

Comment: yes, your separator is correct but it seems like there is something wrong in your category url

Comment: thanks @DineshYadav  for comfirm separator am not sure for this. Now i will try again

Answer (score 0):

> **Default Category/Main/sub, Default Category/Main2/sub2**

It's working!

i can import when i do this 
Default Category/Main/sub, Default Category/Main2/sub2

i think problem about new line in one cell on csv file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/114237)

Comment: i can't import when i do this
Default Category/Main/sub ,
Default Category/Main2/sub2

i can import when i do this
Default Category/Main/sub, Default Category/Main2/sub2

i think problem about new line in one cell on csv file